# I can't set field to NULL on flutter firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web, dart-null-safety

I use JSON serialization to upload documents to firestore.

I just updated my flutter project to nullsafety and now i get this error on any NULL field:

> Error: [cloud_firestore/unknown] Expected a value of type 'Object', but got one of type 'Null'

My fields in class are nullabe:

> String? field;

Is this a bug or am i doing something wrong?
I was able to have null fields before this update. I use web build

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new Cloud Firestore library cannot store null values because of the new null safety feature. I would recommend you use a keyword, like an empty space or intricate piece of string as your custom null variable which should work
Declare

```
String newNull = 'IntricateNull';
```

Pass to Firestore

```
'nullValue':newNull
```

Use it when receiving data

```
if (value != newNull){//To check value is not null
}
```

Its not a favorable solution but it is what it is. Null safety has its downsides and upsides.

Comment: You are right, storing null values seems to be are out of the question. My solution was to use JsonKey like so: @JsonKey(includeIfNull: false) String? field;

Comment: Its your choice. I assume it should work but you should check that once